# Using int main(int argc, char **argv) in c++

Tags: c++, class, program-entry-point, argv

I'm encountering a problem trying to use `char** argv` from the `main`. My goal is to use `argv[2]` to pass to a string in another class called `Game`. Does someone have an idea how I can use `argv` and pass it as a string to another class?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Game game(argv[2]);
  game.runsecondmethod();
}
```

And in `Game.cpp`:

```
Game::Game(std::string a)
{
   write.filename = a;
}
```

```
error, no match for call to (Game)(char*&)
```

Comment: You can't pass an array of pointers to char to some class as a string.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the code you are having problems with?

Comment: A common way of writing the type of `argv` is `char* argv[]`. This way you can easily see that you can write `argv[2]` to access the second argument of your program, which you can then convert into an `std::string` using one of its constructors. Note that `argv[0]` stores the name your program was started with.

Comment: `Game game(std::string(argv[2]));`

Comment: @Erry07 The code you showed should compile. Could you show the full text of the error mesage? Also check whether constructor Game(std::string a) is declared inside the class definition.

Comment: The code you posted works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't actually provided code that exhibits your problem but, to answer your question, ways to pass `argv[2]` as a string to a function include

```
  #include <cstring>
  #include <iostream>
  void func(const char *s)
  {
       //  treat s as a zero terminated string

       if (std::strcmp(s, "Hello") == 0)
       {
            std::cout << "You said hello\n";
       }
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      if (argc >= 3)
        func(argv[2]);
      else
         std::cout << "You have not supplied an argv[2]\n";
  }
```

or

```
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  void func2(const std::string &s)
  {
       if (s == "Hello")
       {
            std::cout << "You said hello\n";
       }
  }

  int main(int argc, char **argv)
  {
      if (argc >= 3)
        func2(argv[2]);
      else
         std::cout << "You have not supplied an argv[2]\n";
  }
```

The first example above (apart from usage of `std` namespace, `std::cout` and C++ headers) is essentially vanilla C.

The second example uses the `std::string` class, so comparison of strings is possible using the `==` operator.   Note that `main()`, when calling `func2()` implicitly converts `argv[2]` into an `std::string` (since `std::string` has a constructor that permits that conversion) that is then passed to the function.

In both cases, `main()` checks `argc` to ensure that 2 (or more) arguments have been passed to it.